How do I install Firmata so I can access it through the IDE on a computer that doesn't have internet access?
I recently installed arduino 2.3.2 IDE on to a computer without internet access, however, the Firmata library I had been using on the original computer which was the one I transferred the arduino15 folder from did not transfer. The original computer had firmata in its contributed library and the correlating sketches. How will I be able to transfer the firmata library onto the new computer using a thumbdrive?

You mean like copying the folder from your old libraries folder into the one on the new computer? Or downloading it here and then copying it to the new libraries folder?

Either way would work, I was just expecting the sketch examples files with the fermata to transfer over as well.  Where would the default library folder be after install? I am fairly new to Arduino so don't know where all the data and library files go. If I were to download it then move it over is there a specific path/folder I need to put the firmata folder in?

The libraries are placed in the libraries directory, inside your sketchbook location. When you open the Preferences in the Arduino IDE there should be an option, where you can see the current sketchbook location. Inside there you should have the libraries directory, where you can place the libraries.
You can either copy the corresponding directory for the Firmata firmware from your old libraries folder on an USB stick, or you can download it from firmatas Github page (either by cloning with the git command or by downloading as ZIP archive (by clicking the green "code" button at the top right and then clicking "Download ZIP") and placing the (unzipped) directory in your libraries folder.
To move your libraries to a new computer, you can just copy everything in the libraries folder. Examples for these libraries are provided with the library files, so when the library is not there, the examples won't be there.

Thanks for the answer, I'll give it a try.
